# how to read/write resource file in .net winform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I am trying to read/write the resource file but couldnt succeed. It seems very easy but I couldnt understand why it gives an exception. the exception is "System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException"

I named the .resx file to Settings.resx  and my code is like below

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Settings", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
String str = rm.GetString("merkez_bankasi_url");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

should it be inside a specific folder for the system to find the resource file?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or some other IDE?

Comment: I am using VS.NET 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Resources I put in a String GoogleURL and a value http://www.google.com

```
    Console.Writeline(Resources.GoogleURL);
```

or in your case

```
    Console.Writeline(Resources.merkez_bankasi_url);
```

Comment: how do you write to .resx file?

Comment: @ayilmaz At design time you'd do it through the resource editor.  At runtime you pretty much don't.  If you're looking for read/write settings you'll want to add a settings file to your project under project properties.

Comment: Might want to use a xml file you can write to update and come back and read anytime.

Comment: what do you mean? what kind of file should I use?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? XML is good for config/setting lite storage. Instead of using a database.